# Using macros in gnuplot 4.6.3

Tags: macros, gnuplot

I tried to find a similar error described on the web but did not find anything. Hope someone can help.

I use a code similar to this example with gnuplot 4.4p3:

```
set macros
col_TIME = '1'
col_meas = '2'
range = 'using ($@col_TIME/3600):@col_meas'
plot "file.txt" @range
```

But with gnuplot 4.6p3 it raises an error while executing the very last line. It correctly substitutes to

```
plot "file.txt" using ($@col_TIME/3600):@col_meas
```

first but then complains about the first @ in this line with "invalid character @".

Comment: my workaround for the new version is now using code like `range = 'using($'.col_TIME.'/3600):'.col_meas`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same thing as your workaround, but I would probably use `sprintf`:

```
range = sprintf('using ($%d/3600):%d',col_TIME,col_meas)
```

Newer versions of gnuplot also support the `eval` command which might be useful.  The following is the example provided in the builtin help:

```
set_label(x, y, text) \
     = sprintf("set label '%s' at %f, %f point pt 5", text, x, y)
eval set_label(1., 1., 'one/one')
eval set_label(2., 1., 'two/one')
eval set_label(1., 2., 'one/two')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like the printf version a lot because it is much easier to read.